# Why is the fact that the sequence $(M_n)_{n\geq0}$ is increasing shown in the following way? My alternative

Tags: sequences-and-series, probability-theory, martingales, supremum-and-infimum

I quote **Jacod-Protter**

---

> Given a probability space $\left(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\mathbb{P}\right)$ and an increasing sequence of $\sigma$-algebras $\left(\mathcal{F}_n\right)_{n\geq0}$, let $M=\left(M_n\right)_{n\geq0}$ be a sequence of integrable r.v.'s, each $M_n$ being $F_n$-measurable and $M_n^{*}=\sup_{j\leq n} |M_j|$

At this point it is stated that:

> Note that ($M_n^{*}$) is an increasing process and a submartingale, since
>   \begin{equation}
> \mathbb{E}[{M_n^{*}]} \leq \mathbb{E}\left[\sum_{j=1}^{n}|M_j|\right]<\infty
> \end{equation}

that is, $\mathbb{E}[{M_n^{*}]} \leq \mathbb{E}\left[\sum_{j=1}^{n}|M_j|\right]<\infty$ implies that ($M_n^{*}$) is an increasing process (and so a submartingale as well, since an increasing sequence of integrable r.v.'s, each being $\mathcal{F}_n$-measurable, is a submartingale, and I know how to prove this).

---

However, my question is: why in the above text is it stated that $\mathbb{E}[{M_n^{*}]} \leq \mathbb{E}\left[\sum_{j=1}^{n}|M_j|\right]<\infty$ **implies that** ($M_n^{*}$) is an increasing process (and so a submartingale as well)?

In which aspect does the inequality $\mathbb{E}[{M_n^{*}]} \leq \mathbb{E}\left[\sum_{j=1}^{n}|M_j|\right]<\infty$ (which is clearly correct in its formulation) tell me that ($M_n^{*}$) is an increasing process? Would not it be more correct to simply state that, by definition of $\sup$ function, for each $m<n$:
\begin{equation}
M_n^{*}=\sup_{j\leq n}|M_j|> M_m^{*}=\sup_{j\leq m}|M_j|
\end{equation}
which means, by definition, that ($M_n^{*}$) is an increasing sequence?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$(M_n^*)_n$ is clearly an increasing process since by definition it is a running maximum. The inequality $\mathbb{E}[M_n^*] \leq \mathbb{E}\sum_{j=1}^n |M_j|$ is used to prove that $M_n^*$ is integrable, which is needed to prove that it's a submartingale.

Comment: Yeah, I was giving this fact for granted. Thank you a lot! @Michh